# PDE with Laplace transform 4

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

I'm trying to solve this problem via Laplace transform, but something sounds me wrong.

\begin{cases}
u_x-4xu_t=0\\
u(x,0)=0\\
u(0,t)=t+3
\end{cases}

My passages:

\begin{cases}
\mathcal{L}[u_x]-\mathcal{L}[4xu_t]=\mathcal{L}[0]\\
u(x,0)=0\\
\mathcal{L}[u(0,t)]=\mathcal{L}[t+3]
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
W_x(x,s)-4x(sW(x,s) - u(x,0)) =0\\
u(x,0)=0\\
\displaystyle W(0,s)=\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{3}{s}
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
W_x(x,s)-4xsW(x,s)=0\\
\displaystyle W(0,s)=\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{3}{s}
\end{cases}

Solving the first ODE, using $\Phi(s)$

\begin{cases}
\displaystyle W(x,s) =\Phi(s)e^{2sx^2} \\
\displaystyle W(0,s)=\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{3}{s}
\end{cases}

So, obtaining $\Phi(s)$

$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{3}{s}=W(0,s)=\Phi(s)$$

$$\displaystyle \Phi(s)=\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{3}{s}$$

Results

$$\displaystyle W(x,s) =\left(\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{3}{s}\right)e^{2sx^2}$$

With $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$, we obtain

$$u(x,t)=t+3+2x^2$$

that satisfies the PDE, the last condition, but not the second one.
Where am I wrong?
Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Comment: I think you took the inverse wrong. $\mathcal{L}^{-1} \lbrace \left(\frac{1}{s^2} + \frac{3}{s} \right) e^{2sx^2} \rbrace (t)$ is *much* more complicated since there's an exponential in there.

Comment: Check out 1 and 15 in this document http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/auxiliary/inttrans/LapInv5.pdf

Comment: I'm not completely sure that number 15 fits, because in the PDF it's requested to be negative, while I have a positive addendum...in any case, too bad..I thought that the exponential in transformed solution became a delay...that's okay... :)